# Filling SqlDataAdapter under TransactionScope triggers Distributed Transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

The TransactionScope handles perfectly many levels of nested transactions, by adhering to the 'highest' transaction. I'm using nesting TransactionScope with IsolationLevel: ReadCommitted and TransactionScopeOption: Required, exacly as described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx).

Inside the Scope, the call to

`ladpAdapter.Fill(ldstDataSet)`

triggers, as I see in Profiler, DTCTransaction. This results in the exception:

```
System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.
```

Turning on the MSDTC service and configuring it over network security (Network DTC Acces => yes, AllowInbound => yes, AllowOutbound => yes) fixes the error, however is not an acceptable solution, due to lack of support for AlwaysOn prior to sql server 2016 ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms366279(v=sql.110).aspx)).

This appears to not be a problem with multiple connections, as all are closed after use and there is no multithreading in this section.

The code looks something like this (pseudo code):

```
Using transactionScope As TransactionScope = CreateTransactionScope()

SomeFunction()'works fine, calls ExecuteScalar
SomeFunction()'works fine, calls ExecuteScalar
SomeFunction()'works fine, calls ExecuteScalar
SomeFunctionWithFill()'breaks, calls Execute

transactionScope.Complete()
End Using
```

where SomeFunction calls execute or executeScalar, and Execute and ExecuteScalar both do basicly the same:

```
   Try
            Dim lcnnDB As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
            Dim lcmdCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(lstrStoredProcedure, lcnnDB)
            Dim lstrStoredProcedure As String = GetStoredProcedure()
            lcmdCommand.Connection.Open()


            Return lcmdCommand.ExecuteScalar()

    Catch ()'rest ommited
```

but Execute also fills Adapter like this:

```
ladpAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(lstrStoredProcedure, lcnnDB)  
ldstDataSet = New DataSet
ladpAdapter.Fill(ldstDataSet)
```

Why is a call to Fill() elevating to DTC transaction? Is it because it uses default incompatible serializable transaction under the hood?

Thanks for any clues and observations.

Related SO articles:

- [SqlDataAdapter.Fill() within a SqlTransaction - is this a bad
  practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295596/sqldataadapter-fill-within-a-sqltransaction-is-this-a-bad-practice)
- [Why is TransactionScope using a distributed
  transaction (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721620/why-is-transactionscope-using-a-distributed-transaction-when-i-am-only-using-lin)
- [TransactionScope automatically escalating to MSDTC on some machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693795/3922292)
- [Refactoring ADO.NET - SqlTransaction vs. TransactionScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270981/refactoring-ado-net-sqltransaction-vs-transactionscope)

Comment: You should show more code. Are you using multiple connections in the transaction-scope?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple connections, however, they are closed after use, and not elevate to DTC, only using connection with Adapter.Fill() elevates.

Comment: any updates on this?